# how to save Keras Model instance of class

Tags: python, keras, model, save, encoder

am using an Seq2Seq project from Google that use Encoder/Decoder, there is the 2 encoder and decoder class :

```
#ENCODER
class EncoderNetwork(tf.keras.Model):
    def __getstate__(self):
        d = self.__dict__.copy()
        d.pop('_parents', None)
        return d

    def __init__(self,input_vocab_size,embedding_dims, rnn_units ):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=input_vocab_size,
                                                           output_dim=embedding_dims)
        self.encoder_rnnlayer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(rnn_units,return_sequences=True, 
                                                     return_state=True )
        encoder_embedding = self.encoder_embedding
        encoder_rnnlayer = self.encoder_rnnlayer

#DECODER
class DecoderNetwork(tf.keras.Model):
    def __getstate__(self):
        d = self.__dict__.copy()
        d.pop('_parents', None)
        return d 
    def __init__(self,output_vocab_size, embedding_dims, rnn_units):
        super().__init__()
        self.decoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=output_vocab_size,
                                                           output_dim=embedding_dims) 
        self.dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_vocab_size)
        self.decoder_rnncell = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(rnn_units)
        # Sampler
        self.sampler = tfa.seq2seq.sampler.TrainingSampler()
        # Create attention mechanism with memory = None
        self.attention_mechanism = self.build_attention_mechanism(dense_units,None,BATCH_SIZE*[Tx])
        self.rnn_cell =  self.build_rnn_cell(BATCH_SIZE)
        self.decoder = tfa.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(self.rnn_cell, sampler= self.sampler,
                                                output_layer=self.dense_layer)

    def build_attention_mechanism(self, units,memory, memory_sequence_length):
        return tfa.seq2seq.LuongAttention(units, memory = memory, 
                                          memory_sequence_length=memory_sequence_length)
        #return tfa.seq2seq.BahdanauAttention(units, memory = memory, memory_sequence_length=memory_sequence_length)

    # wrap decodernn cell  
    def build_rnn_cell(self, batch_size ):
        rnn_cell = tfa.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper(self.decoder_rnncell, self.attention_mechanism,
                                                attention_layer_size=dense_units)
        return rnn_cell

    def build_decoder_initial_state(self, batch_size, encoder_state,Dtype):
        decoder_initial_state = self.rnn_cell.get_initial_state(batch_size = batch_size, 
                                                                dtype = Dtype)
        decoder_initial_state = decoder_initial_state.clone(cell_state=encoder_state) 
        return decoder_initial_state
```

i create an instance of EncoderNetwork and DecoderNetwork with my argument and use the loss_function and train_step already defined to train my model

```
def loss_function(y_pred, y):

    #shape of y [batch_size, ty]
    #shape of y_pred [batch_size, Ty, output_vocab_size] 
    sparsecategoricalcrossentropy = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True,
                                                                                  reduction='none')
    loss = sparsecategoricalcrossentropy(y_true=y, y_pred=y_pred)
    mask = tf.logical_not(tf.math.equal(y,0))   #output 0 for y=0 else output 1
    mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=loss.dtype)
    loss = mask* loss
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
    return loss


def train_step(input_batch, output_batch,encoder_initial_cell_state):
    #initialize loss = 0
    loss = 0
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        encoder_emb_inp = encoderNetwork.encoder_embedding(input_batch)
        a, a_tx, c_tx = encoderNetwork.encoder_rnnlayer(encoder_emb_inp, 
                                                        initial_state =encoder_initial_cell_state)

        #[last step activations,last memory_state] of encoder passed as input to decoder Network


        # Prepare correct Decoder input & output sequence data
        decoder_input = output_batch[:,:-1] # ignore <end>
        #compare logits with timestepped +1 version of decoder_input
        decoder_output = output_batch[:,1:] #ignore <start>


        # Decoder Embeddings
        decoder_emb_inp = decoderNetwork.decoder_embedding(decoder_input)

        #Setting up decoder memory from encoder output and Zero State for AttentionWrapperState
        decoderNetwork.attention_mechanism.setup_memory(a)
        decoder_initial_state = decoderNetwork.build_decoder_initial_state(BATCH_SIZE,
                                                                           encoder_state=[a_tx, c_tx],
                                                                           Dtype=tf.float32)

        #BasicDecoderOutput        
        outputs, _, _ = decoderNetwork.decoder(decoder_emb_inp,initial_state=decoder_initial_state,
                                               sequence_length=BATCH_SIZE*[Ty-1])

        logits = outputs.rnn_output
        #Calculate loss

        loss = loss_function(logits, decoder_output)

    #Returns the list of all layer variables / weights.
    variables = encoderNetwork.trainable_variables + decoderNetwork.trainable_variables  
    # differentiate loss wrt variables
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, variables)

    #grads_and_vars – List of(gradient, variable) pairs.
    grads_and_vars = zip(gradients,variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    return loss
```

the training does not use fit() methode but like this :

```
epochs = 20
for i in range(1, epochs+1):

  encoder_initial_cell_state = initialize_initial_state()
  total_loss = 0.0

  for ( batch , (input_batch, output_batch)) in enumerate(dataset.take(steps_per_epoch)):
      batch_loss = train_step(input_batch, output_batch, encoder_initial_cell_state)
      total_loss += batch_loss
      if (batch+1)%5 == 0:
          print("total loss: {} epoch {} batch {} ".format(batch_loss.numpy(), i, batch+1))
```

the result are fine and the predict fonction work perfectly (custom predict function), but how can i save the model ? i tried pickel and keras.save() but it doesn't work any idea ?

Comment: You need to be really specific on the "does not work" part

Comment: this is the result of .save() function after training, the problem Tthere's no fit() methode, the training is custom

` Model <__main__.EncoderNetwork object at 0x000001C2DF995F88> cannot be saved because the input shapes have not been set. Usually, input shapes are automatically determined from calling .fit() or .predict(). To manually set the shapes, call model._set_inputs(inputs). `